# How to refresh the Java servlet page automatically

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, web-applications

I am developing a web application based on a Java servlet.

Behind the Java servlet, a thread works. The Java servlet outputs html and java script codes. Thus, html and java script codes dynamically vary by a thread.

I made the following codes. html and javascript codes are output by `response.getWriter().println()`.

The problem is; when a thread is completed, nothing is shown. 
However, when I manually refresh the page (Ctrl-R) after a thread is done, I get the page that I expected.

```
<head>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function start()
{
$('#load_latest').load('./PubRecommendation' + ' #load_latest');
}, 2000);
</script>           
</head>


if (result == null) {
    // the variable result is received from a behind thread every 2 seconds. 
    // while a thread is processed
    <div id=\"load_latest\">
    <p>Currently processing. <p>
    </div>
} else {
    // a thread is completed
    <div id="refresh">
    <p>Process is done. <p>
    </div>
}
```

I already tried `location.reload()`, but it did not work.

Comment: Why are you using `load`?

Comment: There are two ways to do this, one you do a pull (which is to use meta-refresh) and pull data from your server every 30 seconds or so. Second way is to Push data from your server to your page, see Atmosphere Framework at [Async-IO](http://async-io.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to refresh the page I have used this before just put this at the end of your html or jsp page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cookie = ("" + document.cookie);
if(!cookie.match(/\S/))
{
    document.cookie = "refresh";
    location.reload(true);
}
else
{
    document.cookie = "refresh; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
}
</script>
```

This will set a cookie the first time the page is loaded then will automatically refresh and it will check the cookie and if it's been refreshed once then it will not reload the second time and will delete the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

The term is [Meta Refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). Searching Google will give you enough examples.

For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=/PubRecommendation#load_latest">
```

Would load your page in 5 seconds after the last load completed.